# Consider the function $\theta=\{0,1\}\times\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ defined as $\theta(a,b)=a-2ab+b$

Tags: functions, proof-verification, proof-writing

Please examine my proof below. New to proofs involving functions. I'm wondering specifically, do I need case 3 in my injective proof? And also, is my proof correct? I know there is another post about this same question but it does not involve a rigorous proof such as this.

Consider the function $\theta=\{0,1\}\times\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ defined as $\theta(a,b)=a-2ab+b$. Is $\theta$ injective? Surjective? Both (bijective)? Or neither?

To show that $\theta$ is injective we will use proof by contraposition.

$Proof$. Suppose $\theta(a,b)=\theta(c,d)$ then $a-2ab+b=c-2cd+d$. But since the arguments to our function are the cross-product of $\{0,1\}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ we know the first element of our ordered pair is either $0$ or $1$. Let's look at three cases.

**Case 1.** Suppose $a=c=1$. Then

$$a-2ab+b=c-2cd+d$$
$$1-2b+b=1-2d+d$$
$$-2b+b=-2d+d$$
$$-b=-d$$
$$b=d$$

**Case 2.** Suppose $a=c=0$. Then

$$a-2ab+b=c-2cd+d$$
$$0-0+b=0-0+d$$
$$b=d$$

**Case 3.** Without loss of generality, suppose $a=1$ and $c=0$. Then

$$a-2ab+b=c-2cd+d$$
$$1-2b+b=0-0+d$$
$$1-b=d$$

But these cases show that $\theta(a,b)=\theta(c,d)\Rightarrow (a,b)=(b,d)$ so it follows that $\theta$ is injective.

Let us now show that $\theta$ is surjective. Select an arbitrary element $x\in\mathbb{Z}$. We want to show there is an $(a,b)\in\{0,1\}\times\mathbb{N}$ for which $\theta(a,b)=x$, or $a-2ab+b=x$.

Let's solve our equation first for $a$ then for $b$.

Solving for $a$ we get

$$a-2ab+b=x$$
$$a-2ab=x-b$$
$$a(1-2b)=x-b.$$

Now, since $b\in\mathbb{N}$ we know $1-2b\neq 0$ then

$$a=\frac{x-b}{1-2b}.$$

Solving for $b$ we get

$$a-2ab+b=x$$
$$-2ab+b=x-a$$
$$b(-2a+1)=x-a.$$

Now, since $a\in\{0,1\}$ then $-2a+1\neq0$ so

$$b=\frac{x-a}{-2a+1}.$$

Thus because

$$\left(\frac{x-b}{1-2b},\frac{x-a}{-2a+1}\right)$$

is an $(a,b)$ for which $\theta(a,b)=x.$ It follows that $\theta$ is surjective.

Since we have shown our function is injective and surjective it is bijective. $\Box$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof of injectivity is correct (and case 3 is needed), but your proof of surjectivity is not correct. You are given $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ and want to produce an $(a,b)$ such that $\theta(a,b)=x$. You cannot define $a$ and $b$ in terms of each other.

Instead, think about what the function $\theta$ does. If $a=0$, then $\theta(0,b)=b$. If $a=1$, $\theta(1,b)=1-b$. How can we make one of these equal to $x$? Well it depends on whether $x$ is positive or not. You should be able to complete the proof from here.

Comment: This is probably a silly question but why can't we define the equations in terms of each other?

Comment: Because it doesn't actually tell you what $a$ and $b$ are. If I tell you that I'm two years younger than my sister and she is two years older than me, I haven't actually told you how old we are. There could be instances in which you're told $a$ in terms of $b$ and $b$ in terms of $a$ and that's enough information to solve for $a$ and $b$, but in that case you'd want to just solve for $a$ and $b$.